# Backpropagation in a Network

Tags: machine-learning, math, deep-learning

Hi does anyone know how to solve this. Im really struggling to figuring this one out.

I am unclear of how the backpropagation part would work in this network and how to calculate it for each weight. Also, how you would incorporate 2 epochs.

Consider the following network:
[image: network]

Write the updated value of

(i) W1

(ii) W2

(iii) W3

(iv) W4

(v) W5

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: The sub-questions are ordered somewhat misleading. Answer W5 first; it's back-propagation for a reason.